# jQuery $.each() method not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying an experiment this morning: loop through a number of list items and perform functions on them. Once the function was performed on all of the items I would call the function again (similar to what you would do with a recursive function) and start all over again. Here is the code:

```
function fade(element) {
    var totalElements = element.length - 1;

    $.each(element, function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        $(this).eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                if(index < totalElements) {
                    console.log(index);
                }
            });
        });
    });

}

var $pictures = $('.fader li');
fade($pictures);
```

The HTML is a simple unordered list that you can see in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/AP6qT/

What occurs is that the first `console.log(index)` returns each index in order before the first `fadeIn()` is called. The first fade cycle is called and the second `console.log(index)` occurs, outputting only a 0.

What is happening here? Why doesn't `$.each()` cycle through each image and perform the functions and why does console log spit out all of the indexes immediately?

EDIT: I am going to experiment with the other form of each to see if I get the same results.

Comment: I think the behoviour of the console is not as straightforward as we may think and will completely depend on the browser

Comment: I don't think `.eq(index)` is doing anything useful for you and can be removed. `this` is already referring to just one element in the callback, due to the context that `$.each` sets for its callback function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).fadeIn(1000, function(){` though instead of `$(this).eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function(){`?

Comment: I removed the `.eq(index)` because that makes sense now that you say it @ajp15243.

Comment: `.fadeIn()` is async, so the loop continues immediately, and all three `fadeIn()`s are started at (pretty close to) the same time. If you want one to fade out before the next fades in, you'll need a different solution.

Comment: Jason P said what I was going to say.  I'll just add that fadeIn() and other animations allow for callbacks which is what you want to do if you want them animations to happen one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `each()`, `this` refers to the *current* element. In this case, it'll be a **single** HTML element.

You're wrapping that **single** HTML element in a jQuery object, but then calling `eq(index)` on that jQuery object which contains only **one** element.

Once you get past `index == 0`, nothing is being matched by `eq()`, resulting in an empty jQuery object, resulting in no *actual* `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` calls being made on the elements you think they are being. This is why you only see `fadeOut` on the first element.

Simply remove `eq(index)`, and [it'll work](http://jsfiddle.net/AP6qT/1/). You won't see `console.log(2)`, because you're specifically excluding it with your `if` condition.

Comment: Still not working as I would expect. I removed the first `console.log()`. Picture 3 fades in and then out, then I run the console.log which returns all of the indexes. It's a head scratcher.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: It *is* working as it should do. All the images are fading in at once, and all fading out at once. That's what your code is asking it to do. See http://jsfiddle.net/AP6qT/2/ to see this in action clearer. What do you want to see?

Comment: I though each image would fade in and out in turn. Maybe I just haven't had enough coffee this morning.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: For that you'll need to `delay()` the other elements until the ones before it have finished. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/AP6qT/3/ (note the `delay(index * 2500)`). Coffee always helps, by the way ;). Like Jason P mentioned in his comment, `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are asynchronous. `each()` doesn't wait for them to complete before it increments.